# Xamarin Essentials and Xamarin Forms package conflict

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When trying to add Xamarin.Forms & Xamarin.Essentials to my android project I get this -

```
Resolving conflicts for MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1...
NU1107: Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. 
Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue. 
abc.android -> Xamarin.Essentials 0.11.0-preview -> Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs 27.0.2.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2.1) 
abc.android -> Xamarin.Forms 3.4.0.1008975 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 27.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2).
```

Looks like they both want to use 27.0.2.1 vs 27.0.2 of Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.

Could someone explain how I resolve this conflict? 
I am not sure what it means by reference the package directly?

Can I add something to my csproj?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/troubleshooting) and follow the link to the blog post. It'll show you how to fix it

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for that link, I just came about Redths article directly in the meantime, appreciate your heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I have since found this very nice article from Redth -

https://redth.codes/how-to-fix-the-dreaded-version-conflict-nuget-error-in-your-xamarinandroid-projects

I added -

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" Version="27.0.2.1" />        
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" Version="27.0.2.1" />        
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" Version="27.0.2.1" />
```

Which got Essentials installed, but I still get these warnings -

```
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette 27.0.2 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils (= 27.0.2) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 27.0.2.1 was resolved.
```

Yet, I think I can see these types of errors in Redths solution, so I think I will assume we are good to go for now.

Comment: the page is not found anymore.

Comment: link updated, thanks